# Merge multi-robot's maps

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I want to know whether navigation_tutorials can merge multi-robot's maps? Or just try to control different robots? Is it real time, or just offline?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/334930/merge-multi-robot%27s-maps/) by [arahp](https://answers.ros.org/users/46852/arahp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2019-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem of merging maps between robots is a slam problem. There are different solutions to do slam in ROS.
(Amongst others [gmapping](https://wiki.ros.org/slam_gmapping), [hector slam](https://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam) and [cartographer](https://wiki.ros.org/cartographer))

One solution that is known to support multiple agents is  **cartographer**: https://google-cartographer-ros.readthedocs.io/en/latest/going_further.html#multi-trajectories-slam

---

Originally posted by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) with karma: 862 on 2019-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arahp](https://answers.ros.org/users/46852/arahp/) on 2019-10-21**:
Thanks a lot, if i want to merge maps using gmapping, do you have any suggestion? For example, a framework to realize it or some related work? It seems that Gmapping does not have this function itself.

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2019-11-20**:
can you please click on the little checkmark next to this answer, then.

**Comment by [Ga_phantom](https://answers.ros.org/users/47311/ga_phantom/) on 2020-03-10**:
There's a package called multirobot_map_merge can merges maps.

**Comment by [Ga_phantom](https://answers.ros.org/users/47311/ga_phantom/) on 2020-03-15**:
I have some problem with /start_trajectory, like it will say topic [scan] is already used.can you speak more specific about it,Thanks in advance.

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2020-03-17**:
This is cartographer specific, yes? I am not an expert on that. I would suggest opening a new question and clearly describe the problem you have with cartographer.

**Comment by [Ga_phantom](https://answers.ros.org/users/47311/ga_phantom/) on 2020-03-22**:
OK, Thank you~.